# Npgsql 3.1.0-beta does support not support framework DNXCore, Version=v.5.0

Tags: .net, postgresql, dnx, npgsql, coreclr

I’m starting a new ASP.NET Core 1.0 project with goal to host it on a Linux machine. I’m trying to use the PostgreSQL data provider Npgsql 3.1.0-beta, which support CoreCLR (.netstandard13) but I get the follow error message:

*NU1002: The dependency Npgsql 3.1.0-beta0001 in project XXX does not support framework DNXCore,Version=v5.0*

Here my proect.json:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "compilationOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Npgsql": "3.1.0-beta0001"
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel"
  },

  "frameworks": {    
    "dnxcore50": { }
  },

  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ]
}
```

Sorry the new .NET Core world is pretty new to me. Thanks, Stefan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Npgsql 3.1.0-beta0001 targets RC2, whereas your application is RC1.

Note that RC2 is about to be released by Microsoft - it's a matter of days. Npgsql 3.1.0 will be released very soon after that.

Comment: thanks! Do you know a how to upgrade to RC2 tutorial? I can't find anything.. thanks again

Comment: Wait until mid next week, Microsoft will be releasing it officially by then

Comment: FYI Npgsql 3.1.0 has been released, targeting rc2